# How to run for loop after html() function finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to run some javascript code only after writing some text in a div as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Tutorial</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="btnTest">Click</button>
    <div id="testDiv" style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#btnTest').on('click', function() {
        $('#testDiv').html('hello');

        for(var i=0; i<5000; i++) {
            console.log('testing');
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

I want the text 'hello' to be displayed inside the div as soon as the button is clicked, and only after that I want the for loop to execute. However, the text appears only while the for loop is running.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML is already placed into the `#testDiv`, but since Javascript blocks the browser until it finishes executing the entire code, you can't see the text there.

So, if you use a `setTimeout` function, then the text will be visible for you before the browser starts executing the loop, since there will be enough time between the execution and the next one:

```
$('#btnTest').on('click', function() {
  $('#testDiv').html('hello');

  setTimeout(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
      console.log('testing');
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan: how is it unnecessary? it works, and without the timeout it doesn't...

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan although the other answer is much better and a better practice than mine, the amount of code written is exactly the same (31 characters): `promise().done(function() {});` to `setTimeout(function() {},0);`

Comment: This is working, thanks.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan as you can see, the other answer had to be edited, since it wasn't working, and he had to put a `delay(0)`, doing in a weird and not needed way, what I've done here.

Comment: @Buzinas got it. my bad.

Answer (score 8):

you can use [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) method:

```
$('#btnTest').on('click', function() {
    $('#testDiv').html('hello').delay(0).promise().done(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            console.log('testing');
        }
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94vf2a6n/)

Comment: That sounds promising :)

Comment: It's not working for me. Still the effect is similar.

Comment: @FREAKYHUNTER If you're using jQuery  version before 1.6 it'll not work, `promise` was introduced in v 1.6

Comment: @Tushar look in the question.. he is using 1.11.3.. It should work.. but who knows how he tested it :)

Comment: @FREAKYHUNTER Check the console, are you getting any error,  MateiMihai maybe you should add working demo in the answer

Comment: @Tushar using 1.11.3 didn't give any errors, and I also tested using v1.8.3, again not working for me.

Comment: @MateiMihai just chrome 44.0.2403.155. Do you think it's the browser issue?

Comment: I've updated the answer. It should work now.. I've added a demo on jsfiddle.. good luck!

Comment: @MateiMihai The updated code is working now. Thanks.